# How do i print from a json string array using javascript within html code

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, excel

[Example output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JtQo.png)
I have a JSON file which I populate from excel via a bit of vba code. It comes out in the format of:

```
[{"Name":"testing1","Data":"15"},{"Name":"testing2","Data":"1"},{"Name":"testing3","Data":"3"}]
```

I wish to take this data to an HTML webpage. I want to print it as a simple list.
I've printed from a json object using something like:

```js
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
        var people = response.people;

        var output = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
            //console.log(people[i].name);
            output += '<li>' + "Name: " + people[i].name + " Age:" + people[i].age + '</li>';
        }
        document.getElementById('people').innerHTML = output;
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "people.json", true);
xhttp.send();
```

I want to know how to change it to print from the string array without the object.

Comment: Can you add the exact output you are expecting ?

Comment: _"string array without the object"_ what do you mean by this? You don't want to use `people[i].` or something of that nature?

Comment: It is what i expect at the moment. I want to configure the file above so it prints from the array of strings. My above code prints to the html webpage using another json file and the object notation.

Comment: Add some screenshot how its should look in the html page

Comment: I've added a link to the image. It doesn't matter what the data is but I want it to come out in a simple list.